# How can I change the default encoding type Thunderbird uses when composing a new email?

Tags: thunderbird, encoding, utf-8

Whenever I compose a new email message in Thunderbird, it defaults to the Western (ISO-8859-1) encoding, and I have to manually change it to UTF-8 every time.

How do I change the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Thunderbird 78+:

**Menu > Options > General > Language & Appearance > Advanced button > Text encoding**

[image: Text encoding settings in Thunderbird 78]

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer that applies to more recent versions of Thunderbird! :)

Comment: Don't you just love how it seems to change in every... single... version... ? ;p

Comment: This (the whole contents of the red frame) seems to be gone in TB 91+ - any idea if it still is customizable?

Answer (score 56):

Tools → Options → Display → Formatting → Fonts → Advanced... → Character Encodings → Outgoing Mail:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Well, that is somewhat illogical to put it there … Thanks!

Comment: In linux it's Edit > Preferences > Display...

Comment: Agreed that it's illogical : you'd expect it to be in "Composition", not "Display". Completely defeats principle of least surprise. They could at least adopt a prefs dialog like Eclipse that will filter to aid discovery of obtuse settings.

Comment: Display... on THEIR machine!

Answer (score 13):

For Thunderbird 17 on the Mac, you can find this setting at:

```
Thunderbird > Preferences > Display > Formatting > Advanced
```

Look at the Character Encodings section, as seen here:

[image]

Comment: Regarding your comment; I did test it and it is the very same path, only with `Edit` except `Thunderbird` under Icedove@Debian and the dialog also looks the same (except for the theme, obviously).

Comment: Great.  Add a new answer with screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OS X you have to use the Config Editor (also know as about:config) found in Preferences -> Advanced -> General. Change the value of the preference named `mailnews.send_default_charset` to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

On Thunderbird 68:

```
Edit>
    Preferences>
        Display>
            Formatting>
                Font & Colors>
                    Advanced (button) > 
                        Text encodings
```

Comment: Thunderbird, not Firefox. Are the menus the same?

Comment: Sorry I meant Thunderbird.