# Default outgoing email encoding for Thunderbird 7.x and later

Tags: email, thunderbird, encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change Thunderbird default encoding?](https://superuser.com/questions/288571/change-thunderbird-default-encoding)

How can I force Thunderbird 7.x to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for outgoing emails?

Superuser has an answered question [How can I change the default encoding type Thunderbird uses when composing a new email?](https://superuser.com/questions/288571/change-thunderbird-default-encoding), but that makes references to settings that are no longer available in current Thunderbird versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just verified that Thunderbird 7.0.1 on Windows has the same setting at exactly the same place.

[image: Tools - Options]

[image: Display - Formatting - Advanced]

[image: Outgoing Mail]