# Unadvisable to use UTF-8 for mails?

Tags: email, thunderbird, encoding, utf-8, charset

Thunderbird (in German) uses the charset `ISO-8859-15` (or `-1`, can't check right now) by default for outgoing and incoming mails. (If you want to change the default, see [How can I change the default encoding type Thunderbird uses when composing a new email?](https://superuser.com/q/288571/151741))

I wonder why TB doesn't use `UTF-8` as default. So I searched for it and the only reason I found was, that some older mail servers and clients couldn't handle UTF-8. I read the [issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224391) (closed as "WONTFIX"), but couldn't find a concrete list which servers/clients/providers would have problems handling UTF-8.

**Will you get problems if you send your mails UTF-8 encoded *today*?**

Comment: Postel's principle is a good default. Of course everyone should change that and use utf-8 :·)

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks: One could maybe say that it's an _application_ of Postel's principle, not a violation, if you only send UTF-8 and not all sorts of legacy, incompatible, and often wrongly declared character sets...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mail *servers* shouldn't have any problems at all, since they are not supposed to parse message headers and especially body. The only thing that matters is that the encodings should be supersets of ASCII – which *both* ISO-8859 and UTF-8 are... Besides, many messages still are 7-bit encoded (either Quoted-Printable or Base64) before sending, just *in case* it has to travel through a non-8-bit-clean server (even though all mail servers have been 8-bit-clean in the past 10 years).

Mail *clients*... honestly, I haven't seen any that lack support for UTF-8 for many years. (Perhaps somebody else has?)