# Thunder Bird attachments not in unicode

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird, unicode, patch

I am trying to solve tasks provided by `eudyptula-challenge` for which I have to send attachments in Unicode format. I am using THunderbird 31.0 version. I have tried everything but still i get a reply from them stating the attachments are in base64 .

I have done the changes menionted in the [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/email-clients.txt).

I have tried the changes in this [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/288571/how-can-i-change-the-default-encoding-type-thunderbird-uses-when-composing-a-new)

How to send a attachment in utf-8 format ?

Comment: What does the attachment contain? If it contains characters outside ascii-7, the MUA will usually encode it one way or another (base64, quoted-encoding...) - and can't be sent through SMTP unless the server supports 8BITMIME (99.99999999%).

Comment: File contains c program and a make file. I have saved both in txt extension. How to know if server supports 8BITMIME or not ?

Comment: You do not want to send UTF8 attachments. Use plain ASCII just you would do when sending an actual patch (see [Documentation/SubmittingPatches](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SubmittingPatches)). You might also want to reconsider your usage of Thunderbird. While it is possible to configure it to send plain ASCII attachments, mutt, for example, would do that by default.